# Does hardware die after a few years?

Tags: cpu

I have a very antiquated PC (6 years with Windows 7 installed) and recently it's has been constantly running at high CPU usage. Running Chrome takes CPU usage up to 60%. I cleaned up the fan and ran a full system scan, and the problem still persists. Does hardware actually die out after a few years?

Comment: Are you asking if something physical breaks down after time from a certain amount of use?!

Comment: Your asking a mix of different things.  Some hardware components do age, and some parts can wear out, but just because it's 6 years old doesn't mean you should expect it to stop working.  And if parts do wear out, they might be easily replaceable.  CPU usage has nothing to do with age (or heat).  That's determined by the tasks it's performing.  As long as the hardware's sitting there and available to process your work, what do you care what the utilization percentage is?  If you're running out of resources, then you can look for the resource hogs and optimize things.

Comment: Consider installing a Linux distribution on your old computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU is almost certainly fine, if the CPU is dying it would not suddenly go slower.

The problem you have is software - as systems get older they tend to acquire more libraries and patches which can make things go slower.  Uninstalling unused programs may help, registry cleaners often help, and reinstalling the OS can help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing lasts forever. That said, its worth looking at what's going on *objectively*

> I have a very antiquated PC (6 years with Windows 7 installed)

While old, those hold up well, I run older machines with minor upgrades.

> and recently it's has been constantly running at high CPU usage.

*Something* has changed. However, sudden high CPU usage is not really a common sign of *hardware* failure.

> Running Chrome takes CPU usage up to 60%

That's not that bad. And how much CPU usage you use depends on what you're doing with what. Still not a sign of hardware failure.

> I cleaned up the fan and ran a full system scan, and the problem still persists.

"Full system scan" dosen't mean anything in particular.

> Does hardware actually die out after a few years?

Yes it does. *Eventually* Capacitors sometimes fail and die. Power regulators explode (I've seen it happen). Systems sometimes simply stop powering up. Rabbits might attack the cables...

That said *Six years* is not that old, and since they sorted out capacitor plague for the most part, its not *that* likely.
Your system isn't dying. A fresh windows 7 install sounds like a *very* good idea tho

Comment: Six years is nothing.  My 37 year old Apple ][e is still running.

Comment: ... I quite literally have nothing that can compete...

Answer (score 0):

CPU will break, but it gives no warning before breaking. The computer will work fine (assuming no other issues), and it will freeze and not start again. CPU lifespan heavily depend on your usage and environment, so it is not easy to tell when a CPU will break.

CPU's speed depend on its clock speed, it is new or 6 years old, the clock speed will not change. However, overheating will cause it to throttle, lowing its clock speed.

Please try the following:

1. Use a software to monitor CPU's temperature, and look up normal temperature of your CPU to see if fans have other issues
2. Check for background processes using CPU, you can try to install a fresh OS to clean up softwares and services that are no longer used

If the problem still persist, then we can conclude that Chrome or websites you are using now require more resources.